# Output results of telnet and nmap to powershell/cmd session

Tags: powershell, cmd, telnet, nmap

So I have a serious fundamental gap in my knowledge that I'm sure has an easy answer, but after googling and looking on here, I can't find what I'm looking for:
I use `nmap` and `telnet` on an almost daily basis for checking ports and logging into `IP codecs` and I use them through either the `powershell` or `cmd` consoles, but when I tried to script something and run that script with either a `.bat` or `.ps1` suffix, either will give me the classic `not recognized...` message. But, if you're able to run it in the console, you should be able to script it, right? How can one go about that?

Sample code for `telnet` (that works in when inputting to either console, but not in script form):

```
telnet 192.168.87.21
```

Sample code for `nmap` (again, works when inputting to either console, but not in script form):

```
nmap -p 9999 192.168.87.101
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @Daniel edited to add. I didn't add it in the beginning, because I figured it wouldn't really be of any help.

Comment: I just created a `.bat` program with the code `telnet 192.168.87.21` and it runs fine. I've also tried with PowerShell and a `.ps1` extension - it also runs fine.

Comment: @Daniel odd...those two didn't work for me. I'll have to dig into why they didn't, in the meantime, there was an answer that helped me with Powershell. Thanks though, I'll have to look into why it didn't work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a '&' symbol before 'telnet' like that: `& telnet 127.0.0.1`

For more information how to run executables from Powershell look there: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that documentation was exactly what I was looking for! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can!

Comment: The invocation operator (`&`) is not necessary if the command name does not contain whitespace. It won't hurt, but it isn't necessary.